# Type or namespace name DBModel could not be found

Tags: c#, asp.net

Trying to follow an asp.net tutorial.  How how to import DBModel() class or what am I doing wrong?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using WebApplication2.Models;


namespace WebApplication2.Controllers
{
    public class CollegeController : Controller
    {
        // GET: College
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }

        public ActionResult GetData()
        {
            using (DBModel db = new DBModel())
            {

            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Am I missing something? DBModel is the class representing your database, so you must create it along with the logic. If you're following a tutorial, download the whole source code and you'll find it...

Comment: Ok that might explain it I did change some names

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Visual Studio or JetBrains Rider:

You need to add the directive to the namespace or assembly reference.

Try putting the cursor above the DBModel word and use key combination: ALT + Enter.

You should see something similar to the image below:

[image: Sample Adding Directive]

Most of the time you'll only see one suggestion. Click on it.